# ExecutionEngineException due to getting SpatialReference parameters

Tags: coordinate-system, arcobjects, .net, arcgis-10.8

We developed an ArcGIS .NET extension. The input datasets are one polygon and one raster layer. At first, we checked the SpatialReference of the layers. If the SpatialReferences are different, we show the SpatialReference parameter values comparison to the user. The tool works fine. But the problem is when the raster layer has a vertical projection and we run it in **ArcGIS 10.8**, **ExecutionEngineException** occurs. Consequences, the ArcMap crashes. 
we observe if we don't read the **SpatialReference** parameter values, no exception occurs.

For getting SpatialReference parameter values, code developed so far:

```csharp
        public bool IsHorizontalParamsSame(ISpatialReference sp1, ISpatialReference sp2)
        {
            var thisParams = GetProjectionParameterValues(sp1);
            var sp2Params = GetProjectionParameterValues(sp2);

            var keys = thisParams.Keys.ToList().Union(sp2Params.Keys.ToList()).ToList();

            if (thisParams.Count != sp2Params.Count) return false;

            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                if (!(sp2Params.ContainsKey(key) && thisParams.Keys.Contains(key))) return false;

                if (sp2Params[key] != thisParams[key]) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, string> GetProjectionParameterValues(ISpatialReference spatialReference)
        {
            var paramList = GetProjectionParameters(spatialReference as IProjectedCoordinateSystem4GEN);

            return GetParamValueDictionary(paramList);
        }

        private IParameter[] GetProjectionParameters(IProjectedCoordinateSystem4GEN projectedCoordinateSystem)
        {
            var parameters = new IParameter[16];

            projectedCoordinateSystem.GetParameters(ref parameters);

            return parameters;
        }

        private Dictionary<string, string> GetParamValueDictionary(IParameter[] parameters)
        {
            var paramValues = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
            {
                IParameter currentParameter = parameters[i];
                if (currentParameter != null)
                {
                   paramValues.Add(currentParameter.Name.ToUpper(),currentParameter.Value.ToString());
                }
            }

            return paramValues;
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What line does it crash on? There's a strong chance that the line causing error is not in the code you supplied. It could be that there are keys that are not in both dicts but that should return a key error, have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138982/what-happens-to-c-sharp-dictionaryint-int-lookup-if-the-key-does-not-exist about retrieving values from keys that might not exist.

Comment: It doesn't crash on a specific line. I am checking your concern. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, I checked again after your comment.
if I comment out all code without following two lines in the IsHorizontalParamsSame method and call it then the issue exists. where sp2 is SpatatialReference of the raster layer.
            var sp2Params = GetProjectionParameterValues(sp2);
            return true;
if i don't call the IsHorizontalParamsSame method, the issue doesn't exist. I think your suspect is not true.

Comment: The System.ExecutionEngineException exception is thrown when the CLR detects that something has gone horribly wrong. This can happen some considerable time after the problem occurred.https://stackoverflow.com/a/4104845/6264842